# Android Studio using issues

Tags: android-studio

I'm a newcomer to Android development, decided to learn something new in my free time. My main expertise lies in backend development with PHP, and I use PHPStorm for coding. At my primary job, I handle a medium-sized project, and PHPStorm performs exceptionally well for run frontend and backend in Docker on my laptop, compared to Android Studio (AS). I'm astonished; when I run a Jetpack starter project, the build alone takes 2-3 minutes on a Pixel 7 Pro API 33. That's only half of the issue—there are constant strange freezes, and the only solution is to kill AS. I've allocated 6 gigabytes of RAM forcefully for AS, but it doesn't help much. Instead of learning a new language, I find myself troubleshooting an applied tool.

Dear friends, could you please advise if there are any settings or configurations I should enable or disable?

I think maybe I need to use another ide?

OS: Linux | Manjaro (GNOME). Laptop, RAM: 16GB, Processor: AMD Ryzen 7 4800H (8 cores, 16 threads, 12MB cache, up to 4.2 GHz).

I've allocated 6 gigabytes of RAM forcefully for AS, but it doesn't help much